# Can I add listener to Circle drawn on the map?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to draw a `Circle` on the map and do something when the user touches it. Also, I can't find any method of `Circle` which is about that. What do I need to do?

Thanks,
Sarun

**Edit**

In order to clarify my question. I want the circle that is have the constant distance relative to the ground, that means, if I zoom the map, the circle will grow bigger.

Comment: Add a marker to the map and give it your own icon.

Comment: @Niek at first, I've thought of that. But I want the `Circle` to have constant radius relative to the map. If I use `Marker`, I'll have a screen-relative radius. By the way, thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using `OnMapClickListener`.

In the callback check if the distance between clicked `LatLng` and the center of the `Circle` is smaller than radius.

[`Location.distanceBetween`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5b%5d%29) should be of some help.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the answer just now. Maybe what you are looking for is marker.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#customize_the_marker_image

Here's the sample to customize marker to circle.

```
private static final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.81319, 144.96298);
  private Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(MELBOURNE)
                            .title("Melbourne")
                            .snippet("Population: 4,137,400")
                            // set your circle pictures here
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.circle_pictures)));
```

---

**Update**

If you need circle to become bigger when zoom-in. My advise is, you have to create a custom circle and make radius become bigger as zoom-in and smaller as zoom-out. This method is completely native, you have write your own code to adapt everything you needs.

```
class CircleMarker extends View{

    private Paint paint;
    private float cx,cy,radius;     

    public CircleMarker(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c){
        c.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, paint);
    }

    public void redrawCirle(float cx, float cy, float radius){
        this.cx = cx;
        this.cy = cy;
        this.radius = radius;
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this circle going to move with the map? The circle I want is the circle that have the center as `LatLng`. Thanks

Comment: OK, I forgot to tell you that, I want the circle that is have the constant distance relative to the ground, that means, if I zoom the map, the circle will grow bigger. The circle you mentioned doesn't grow with map zoom. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried my best. This is the only way I can figure out. Hope there is any other better answer.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried searching it for 2 days. Anyway, thanks for your help.